# Channelling processing power from Linux servers over a gigabit LAN to Macintosh system

Tags: linux, mac, lan, gigabit-ethernet, parallel-processing

As you may know Apple offers a program called Xgrid for sharing processing power between Macs. It also allows for easy clustering.

Is there a way to channel processing power from Linux nodes over a gigabit LAN to a Macintosh system? Essentially you would be creating a super computer and then designating its processing power for use on a single, connected system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been some projects to emulate Xgrid on non-Apple based hardware but the're either discontinued or incompatible with current versions of Xgrid.